# How to add a command line argument to my script?

Tags: bash, shell, command

I have to create an array of counters for files starting with a digit under a directory given as a command line argument. I am having trouble with the command line argument on how to add it and how to do it.

my code is

```
count=0

while [ $count -lt 10 ]

do

   num=$count | wc -l

   echo $count $num

   count=`expr $count + 1`

done
```

my output right now comes out as

```
0 0
1 0
2 0
3 0
4 0 
5 0
6 0
7 0
8 0
9 0
```

Comment: Try this: `for ((i = 0; i < $1; i++)); do a=($i*); echo $i ${#a[@]}; done` ($1 is the first argument to the script.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. write your code in file.sh, make file.sh executable
2. call you script with a argument: . path/file.sh directory
3. you can use "$1" get the argument; the you can use script get the files starting with a digit in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

can you tell us more details about what will your program do and what is the expected result of your program?

To Pass an argument line to the shell script you can use this:

```
$/shellscriptname.sh argument1 argument2
```

You can also access passed arguments with $i where i is the argument number.

- $1 access the first argument.
- $2 access the second argument.

Or you can pass the output of one shell script as argument onto another shell script using this:

```
$/firstshellscriptname.sh "$(secondshellscriptname.sh)"
```

Comment: the program loops through the directory and counts how many files start with a digit and give back how many files started with 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

Comment: basically you want to find all directory that start with numbers (0,1,2,3,...) in a drive?

using find?


           `find . -type d -regextype sed -regex ".*/-[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+`